# SQL : How to aggregate values of one column depending on conditions applied on 2 other columns?

Tags: sql

```
      ID                COL1    COL2    DATE    DATE2       RES
      P4579841254       10      20  01/02/1900  01/04/1914  10
      P4579841254       20      25  01/03/1907  02/08/1918  57
      P4579841254       30      31  01/04/1914  03/12/1922  459
      P4579841254       70      71  01/05/1921  05/04/1927  7895
      P4579841254       70      71  01/06/1921  05/06/1927  2497
      P4579841254       71      20  01/06/1928  06/08/1931  1256
      P4579841254       20      75  01/07/1935  07/12/1935  325987
```

Hello Comm', I want to calculate the sum of the col[RES] by taking as following conditions:

COL1 >= 70 and DATE1 >= min(DATE1)

and

COL2 <= 75 and DATE2 <= max(DATE2)

with,

min(DATE1) taken when COL1=70

and

max(DATE2) taken when COL2=75

In other words I want :
"if we have multiple COL1=70, we take only the one that gets the MIN(DATE) and for the COL2=75 we take the MAX(DATE) of all the rows showing COL2=75, once we have DTmin and DTmax we take all the values of RES column within this interval [DTmin;DTmax] and we sum"

For this ID, the results should be 335138 (sum of row4, row6 and row7)
I tried something with following lines, but it becomes complex for me and my SQL level (for now) when I have to insert those SELECT in others upstream SELECT that enables grouping finally by ID :(

```
(SELECT "DT_MIN" FROM
(SELECT "ID",MIN("DATE1") as DT_MIN
FROM "MY_TABLE"
GROUP BY "ID","DATE1","COL1","COL2"
HAVING  ("COL1"='70')
)) as "DT_MIN_vf",

(SELECT "DT_MAX" FROM
(SELECT "ID",MAX("DATE2") as DT_MAX
FROM "MY_TABLE"
GROUP BY "ID","DATE2","COL1","COL2"
HAVING ("COL2"='75')
))as "DT_MAX_vf"
```

Need your help Specialists !

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: According to your logic, row 5 should be considered in the sum. (COL1 = 70 and 01/06/1921 >= 01/05/1921)

Comment: The expected output is not matching the input data with the specified criteria, or maybe I misunderstand you, i.e. COL1 in row7 should be 70, and COL1 in row5 should NOT be 70.

Comment: Why is row 7 included if col1 < 70? Does it only need to meet one of the criteria?

Comment: @jarlh : SAP Hana

Comment: @iceblade : no because i'd like to get only one DTmin corresponding to the MIN of DATE among all the potential COL1=70

Comment: @Ahmed : no even if we have multiple COL1=70, we take only the one that gets the MIN(DATE) for the 1st condition and for the COL2=75 we take the MAX(DATE) of all the rows showing COL2=75 (don't know if it's more clear now)

Comment: @EdmCoff : row is included because this is the max value (to be clear we only want DTmin<DT<DTmax and each DTmin and DTmax are defined according to COL1 for one and COL2 for the other)
It's tricky this case ^^

Comment: @all : I just add some more details in my question (see before results)

Comment: Does the rule about only getting one of the rows for col1=70 apply to any value there, or is 70 a special case? e.g. If you had 3 rows with col1=71, would you only sum one of them?

Comment: Yes 70 is a special case (my spec if you want) as 75 for COL2.
Then we have to sum all the 71, 72 and son on while they are included in the [DTmin;DTmax] interval

Answer (score 1):

This gives you your expected result, but I'm not sure I'm fully understanding the requirements. Please take [a look at it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d1399659f4dd1341dae51876b3a8313) and let me know if/what I'm misunderstanding.

```
WITH 
 min_d AS
  (SELECT min(m2.date1) d FROM mytable m2 WHERE m2.col1 = 70),
 max_d AS
  (SELECT max(m2.date2) d FROM mytable m2 WHERE m2.col2 = 75)
SELECT id, SUM(res)
FROM mytable
WHERE 
 date1 >= (SELECT d FROM min_d)
 AND (col1 <> 70 OR date1 = (SELECT d FROM min_d)) -- Handles the special case to only include the col1=70 row where date1=min_d, but unclear if it needs to be more general
 AND date2 <= (SELECT d FROM max_d)
GROUP BY id
```

The two CTEs at the top get the min and max dates you want. This is just to avoid duplicating them in the query, but there's no reason they have to be CTEs.

I have the special case for `(col1 <> 70 OR ...)` to ensure it only includes the col1=70 case where date1=min_d. I'm not at all confident I am understanding this rule in general, but this does give you the result you want.

You'll note that `COL1 >= 70` and `COL2 <= 75` do not appear anywhere here, despite you mentioning them in your question. You've said that the `min(date1)` should be calculated for col1=70 (not >=) and you've said that row 7 should be included despite COL1 being < 70, so I'm not sure where `COL1 >= 70` and `COL2 <= 75` is relevant.

Comment: Yes EdmCoff, you absolutely right, cause although COL1 can get lower values than 70 , they are taken into account because of condition 2 reached (=75)...so it's not relevant !!!

Comment: Here is the real case I want to test


I'm facing a "conversion issue", I think it's linked to the fact that COL1 is !=70

Comment: Here is the real case I want to test

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=764f252cf8ee960f32533a4ce3ac1c22

I'm facing a "conversion issue", I think it's linked to the fact that COL1 is !=70, it does'nt want to take the row 6 (by changing date2 for exple to 12/04, the code runs)...BUT the result is still uncorrect !!!
In this very example, the expected sum on the 3 last rows is 3 715 007)
How to make it take at the same time : 
date1>=date1min and (date2<=date2max and >date1min) ?

Comment: @bimice I'm still not understanding your rules: The second last row is being excluded because its date1 (2022-03-01 11:27:00) is less than the date1min (2022-03-01 11:27:28). Isn't one of your rules that date1 be >= date1min? Or is part of the criteria to ignore the time part of the date?

Comment: You can use this version to look at your new data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0bbbe02b9d3e7a972068ac6d3da0cec